# Wifi crashes on ubuntu 23.04, Wi-Fi 6 AX210

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, 23.04

It seems to be random but most of the time within 20 minutes wifi crashes and won't restart until reboot, has happened in about a minute at the earliest. Pretty much makes ubuntu a pain to use, so I have been using windows mostly, this is a dual boot system on two seperate drives with an asus 670e-e gaming wifi motherboard. I formatted the drive and reinstalled ubuntu 23.04 yesterday and the problem still occured. I updated bios to the latest version, turn off fast boot and secure boot. I also had this problem on the 22.04 build before I upgrade to 23.04. It started when I upgraded my system to the current motherboard. I am not the most knowledgeable with ubuntu but, below are some logs that might help. Any help is appreciated, feel free to ask any questions. Thanks

sudo dmesg | grep iwl

```
 $ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    5.161930] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.163972] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    5.163977] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
[    5.164251] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 72.a764baac.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.258781] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    5.410965] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x3f
[    5.410980] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[    5.410993] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[    5.411005] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0
[    5.411184] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded PNVM version 64acdc51
[    5.423073] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[    5.492297] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: base HW address: bc:09:1b:0f:19:5f
[    5.507398] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0 wlp9s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6.512395] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x3f
[    6.512408] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[    6.512420] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[    6.512434] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0
[   97.061445] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
[   97.061453] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 267 write_ptr 268
[   97.079320] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 1052 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2172 __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x192/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   97.079342] Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer nvidia_uvm(POE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd nvidia_drm(POE) kvm_amd iwlmvm nvidia_modeset(POE) btusb snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm mac80211 snd_hda_intel btrtl snd_usb_audio iommu_v2 snd_intel_dspcfg irqbypass btbcm drm_buddy snd_intel_sdw_acpi crct10dif_pclmul snd_usbmidi_lib polyval_clmulni btintel gpu_sched polyval_generic snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi ghash_clmulni_intel drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi_event btmtk libarc4 sha512_ssse3 snd_rawmidi snd_hda_core ttm aesni_intel mc snd_hwdep nvidia(POE) iwlwifi bluetooth drm_display_helper snd_seq snd_pcm crypto_simd cryptd cec snd_seq_device rapl asus_nb_wmi eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof k10temp rc_core ecdh_generic snd_timer ccp ecc cfg80211 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper snd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore joydev input_leds mac_hid msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport efi_pstore dmi_sysfs
[   97.079402] RIP: 0010:__iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x192/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   97.079429]  iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[   97.079442]  iwl_force_nmi+0xe6/0x100 [iwlwifi]
[   97.079455]  iwl_trans_sync_nmi_with_addr+0x14e/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   97.079468]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x47/0x80 [iwlwifi]
[   97.079481]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x359/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[   97.079500]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   97.079515]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x81/0x110 [iwlwifi]
[   97.079527]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x38/0xa0 [iwlmvm]
[   97.079542]  iwl_mvm_request_statistics+0x12e/0x1b0 [iwlmvm]
[   97.079556]  ? __pfx_iwl_wait_stats_complete+0x10/0x10 [iwlmvm]
[   97.079568]  iwl_mvm_mac_sta_statistics+0xeb/0x140 [iwlmvm]
[   97.079826] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   97.079828] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   97.080005] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000000: 27258086 00100000 0280001a 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080007] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00248086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
[   97.080009] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000040: 00028010 10008ec0 001b0c10 0045e812 10120000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080010] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000005 00000006 00000002 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080012] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000080: 000f0011 00002000 00003000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080013] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080014] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000008 00804005 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080016] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080017] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000100: 14c10001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00003000 00000000 00000014 40001001
[   97.080019] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000120: 0000000f fb700460 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080020] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000140: 14c00000 ff000000 000000ff 15410018 00000000 0001001e 00481e1f 00000000
[   97.080021] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   97.080049] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[   97.080050] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[   97.080053] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[   97.080075] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000000: 14c10001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00003000 00000000 00000014 40001001
[   97.080076] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 00000020: 0000000f fb700460 00000000
[   97.080077] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:07:04.0) config registers:
[   97.080207] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000000: 43f51022 00100407 06040001 00010010 00000000 00000000 00090907 800001f1
[   97.080208] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000020: fb70fb70 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000050 00000000 001201ff
[   97.080210] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000040: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00817005 fee00000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080211] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000060: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c8238001 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080213] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000080: 0162c010 00008022 0005291f 007ae813 70120042 00000d00 01480000 00000000
[   97.080214] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00010800 00000000 01870e0e 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080215] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 000000c0: 0000000d 33281b21 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080217] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080218] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000100: 1c010001 00000000 00400000 00462030 00000040 0000e000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080219] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080221] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000140: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 1801000d 0000005f 00000000 00000000
[   97.080222] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000160: 1c010018 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080223] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000180: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080225] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 000001a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080226] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 000001c0: 20010019 00000000 00000000 73787378 73787378 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080227] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 000001e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   97.080228] iwlwifi 0000:07:04.0: 00000200: 2201001e 0079801f 41168000
[   97.098092] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 1052 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwl-trans.h:1418 iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x4c9/0x5b0 [iwlwifi]
[   97.098110] Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer nvidia_uvm(POE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd nvidia_drm(POE) kvm_amd iwlmvm nvidia_modeset(POE) btusb snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm mac80211 snd_hda_intel btrtl snd_usb_audio iommu_v2 snd_intel_dspcfg irqbypass btbcm drm_buddy snd_intel_sdw_acpi crct10dif_pclmul snd_usbmidi_lib polyval_clmulni btintel gpu_sched polyval_generic snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi ghash_clmulni_intel drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi_event btmtk libarc4 sha512_ssse3 snd_rawmidi snd_hda_core ttm aesni_intel mc snd_hwdep nvidia(POE) iwlwifi bluetooth drm_display_helper snd_seq snd_pcm crypto_simd cryptd cec snd_seq_device rapl asus_nb_wmi eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof k10temp rc_core ecdh_generic snd_timer ccp ecc cfg80211 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper snd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore joydev input_leds mac_hid msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport efi_pstore dmi_sysfs
[   97.098149] RIP: 0010:iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x4c9/0x5b0 [iwlwifi]
[   97.098173]  iwl_fwrt_dump_error_logs+0x29/0x220 [iwlwifi]
[   97.098186]  iwl_mvm_nic_error+0x7a/0x130 [iwlmvm]
[   97.098200]  iwl_trans_sync_nmi_with_addr+0x7d/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   97.098213]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x47/0x80 [iwlwifi]
[   97.098226]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x359/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[   97.098242]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   97.098254]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x81/0x110 [iwlwifi]
[   97.098267]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x38/0xa0 [iwlmvm]
[   97.098280]  iwl_mvm_request_statistics+0x12e/0x1b0 [iwlmvm]
[   97.098292]  ? __pfx_iwl_wait_stats_complete+0x10/0x10 [iwlmvm]
[   97.098305]  iwl_mvm_mac_sta_statistics+0xeb/0x140 [iwlmvm]
[   97.098540] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[   97.122392] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 72.a764baac.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode
[   97.122395] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   97.122397] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   97.122398] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   97.122399] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   97.122400] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   97.122401] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   97.122402] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   97.122403] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   97.122404] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   97.122405] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   97.122405] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   97.122406] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   97.122407] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   97.122408] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   97.122409] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   97.122410] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   97.122411] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   97.122412] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   97.122413] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   97.122414] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   97.122415] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   97.122416] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   97.122416] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   97.122417] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   97.122418] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   97.122419] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   97.122420] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   97.122421] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   97.122422] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   97.122422] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   97.122423] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   97.122424] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   97.122425] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   97.122426] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   97.140249] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   97.140250] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   97.140251] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink2
[   97.140251] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   97.140252] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   97.140253] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data1
[   97.140253] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data2
[   97.140254] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[   97.140254] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac major
[   97.140255] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac minor
[   97.140255] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | frame pointer
[   97.140256] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | stack pointer
[   97.140256] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   97.140257] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   97.158052] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[   97.158053] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x5A5A | IML/ROM SYSASSERT
[   97.158053] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x5A5A5A5A | IML/ROM error/state
[   97.175847] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x5A5A5A5A | IML/ROM data1
[   97.193640] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x5A5A5A5A | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   97.229233] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
[   97.247052] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Failed to dump region: id=1, type=10
[   97.264855] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Failed to dump region: id=2, type=11
[   97.371767] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to get monitor header
[   97.371768] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Failed to fill region header: id=16, type=2
[   97.443501] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Failed to dump region: id=21, type=10
[   97.461301] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Failed to dump region: id=22, type=10
[  100.439448] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.457245] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.475041] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.492838] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.528437] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5a5a5a5a, CPU2 Status: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.546238] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_LMAC1_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.564036] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: HPM_SECONDARY_DEVICE_STATE: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.581832] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_ADDR: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.599627] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_DATA: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.617469] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.635266] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x5a5a5a5a
[  100.635267] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[  100.670885] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 569 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwl-trans.h:1418 iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x4c9/0x5b0 [iwlwifi]
[  100.670899] Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer nvidia_uvm(POE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd nvidia_drm(POE) kvm_amd iwlmvm nvidia_modeset(POE) btusb snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm mac80211 snd_hda_intel btrtl snd_usb_audio iommu_v2 snd_intel_dspcfg irqbypass btbcm drm_buddy snd_intel_sdw_acpi crct10dif_pclmul snd_usbmidi_lib polyval_clmulni btintel gpu_sched polyval_generic snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi ghash_clmulni_intel drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi_event btmtk libarc4 sha512_ssse3 snd_rawmidi snd_hda_core ttm aesni_intel mc snd_hwdep nvidia(POE) iwlwifi bluetooth drm_display_helper snd_seq snd_pcm crypto_simd cryptd cec snd_seq_device rapl asus_nb_wmi eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof k10temp rc_core ecdh_generic snd_timer ccp ecc cfg80211 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper snd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore joydev input_leds mac_hid msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport efi_pstore dmi_sysfs
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlp9s0
       version: 1a
       serial: bc:09:1b:0f:19:5f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.2.0-25-generic firmware=72.a764baac.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-72.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:24 memory:fb700000-fb703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller I225-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 03
       serial: a0:36:bc:ac:ad:96
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=6.2.0-25-generic firmware=1082:8770 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:35 memory:fb200000-fb2fffff memory:fb300000-fb303fff
```

uname -r

```
$ uname -r
6.2.0-25-generic
```

dkms status

```
$ dkms status
nvidia/535.54.03, 6.2.0-20-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.54.03, 6.2.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed
```

lsmod | grep iwlwifi

```
$ lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               569344  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211             1241088  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

rfkill list

$ rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

sudo iwconfig(This was done before the wifi crashed.)

```
$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlp9s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ss1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: DC:EF:09:B0:3B:5E   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:164   Missed beacon:0
```

sudo iwconfig(After wifi crashes.)

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlp9s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `iwconfig`

Comment: in terminal run `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && systemctl restart network-manager.service` see if that helps any

Comment: after putting that in it came up with a red error. Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.

Comment: Try a reboot and see if problem still occurs

Comment: the problem is still occurring with the same sudo dmesg | grep iwl log, and power management is off in the iwconfig log

Comment: I had this same problem on Ubuntu 22.04.3 with the same 72.a764baac.0 firmware version and the powersave change seems to have resolved it for me. Thanks @Jeremy31 !